# How to get all power plants from Open Street Map using overpass api with python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

This is the code I'm using:

```
import overpass
api = overpass.API(timeout=900)
response = api.Get('node["power" = "plant"]')
print(response)
```

I'm getting a nested dictionary of power plants, but only 187.  I suspect there must be many more. Does anyone know a better way to query?  I eventually want to help build a database of power plants by country and welcome any help on how to query by country as well.

Below, I'm able to query the node using a bounding box:

```
import urllib

workspace = " "

# Make data queries to jXAPI
powerXml = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?node%5Bpower=*%5D%5Bbbox=1.58203,4.56547,15.46875,14.94478%5D").read()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only fetching [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). According to [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/power) about 7% of power plants are mapped as [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) (and very few as [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relations)). Proportions might be different for your country.

You can construct country-specific queries with the help of [overpass-turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). It is a nice frontend to Overpass API, has a nice wizard and also a slightly improved query language. Using the wizard and searching for "power=plant in France" returns the following [query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/gS0):

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“power=plant in France”
*/
[out:json][timeout:300];
// fetch area “France” to search in
{{geocodeArea:France}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “power=plant”
  node["power"="plant"](area.searchArea);
  way["power"="plant"](area.searchArea);
  relation["power"="plant"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Note that you have to increase the timeout (e.g. to 300 seconds) because the default timeout of 25 seconds is pretty low for such large queries.

This query returns about 800 power plants. If you want to call this query from your python script then you will have to transform it back into Overpass language. The `{{geocodeArea:France}}` thing is an extension by overpass turbo and not supported by Overpass API. Go to Export -> Overpass QL and you will get this query:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:180]
;
area(3602202162)->.searchArea;
(
  node
    ["power"="plant"]
    (area.searchArea);
  way
    ["power"="plant"]
    (area.searchArea);
  relation
    ["power"="plant"]
    (area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Now `{{geocodeArea:France}}` has been replaced by `area(3602202162)`. Areas are a special element in Overpass API which don't exist in the same way in OSM. The area ID (in this case) originates from [2202162](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2202162) (relation ID of France) + 3600000000. Note that whenever the relation ID of France changes (highly unlikely) you have to update this number.

You can call this query directly from your application using [this URL](https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%0A%5Btimeout%3A300%5D%0A%3B%0Aarea%283602202162%29-%3E.searchArea%3B%0A%28%0A%20%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22power%22%3D%22plant%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%28area.searchArea%29%3B%0A%20%20way%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22power%22%3D%22plant%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%28area.searchArea%29%3B%0A%20%20relation%0A%20%20%20%20%5B%22power%22%3D%22plant%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%28area.searchArea%29%3B%0A%29%3B%0Aout%20body%3B%0A%3E%3B%0Aout%20skel%20qt%3B) (also available via the export functionality of overpass turbo).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!  

If I may bug you for one more thing - I can query OSM for all cities in Belgium:
```import overpass

api = overpass.API(timeout=900)

cities = api.Get('area[name="België - Belgique - Belgien"];(node[place="city"](area););out;')

print(cities)``` 

but I can't do similar for powerplants.  Do you know why?
```api = overpass.API(timeout=900)

power = api.Get('area[name="België - Belgique - Belgien"];(node[power="plant"](area););out;')

print(power)```

Thanks again

Comment: Follow-up questions at https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50424/query-overpass-api-for-powerplant-in-country-borders and https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/issues/59.

Comment: The error is below.  I'm able to get power plants and power generators when I specify a bounding box, but I'd like a more efficient way to get country level data from the API.

KeyError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-96-529c6ed17161> in <module>() 1

C:\Users\julia.dills\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\overpass\api.py in _asGeoJSON(self, elements) 129 elif elem_type == "way": 130 points = [] --> 131 for coords in elem["geometry"]: 132 points.append((coords["lon"], coords["lat"])) 133 geometry = geojson.LineString(points)

KeyError: 'geometry'

Comment: @JuliaDills: please don't post the same error message on several places, like here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/50424/query-overpass-api-for-powerplant-in-country-borders.

This wastes everyones time.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware.  Won't happen again.